# cannot create a customer profile with authorize.net CIM and active merchant with dev test account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net, activemerchant

I created a developer account with authorize.net and I am trying to create a customer profile via activemerchant.

```
> GATEWAY.create_customer_profile(:profile => { :merchant_customer_id => "123foobar", :email => "lol@lol.com" })

#<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0x007fc3a2663e20 @params={"messages"=>
{"result_code"=>"Error", "message"=>{"code"=>"E00007", "text"=>"User authentication failed 
due to invalid authentication values."}}}, @message="User authentication failed due to 
invalid authentication values.", @success=false, @test=false, @authorization=nil, 
@fraud_review=nil,
@avs_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil},
@cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil}>
```

I looked up that error code and it says:

```
API Error Code: E00007
Error Code Text: User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.
Description: The name/and or transaction key is invalid.
Other Tips: Try switching between production and developer test URL's. The test URL     
requires a separate developer test account, which can be set up by filling out the following form: http://developer.authorize.net/testaccount.
```

Just to be certain, I verified the api login key.. When I inspect the gateway object, I see the login (api login key), password (transaction key), and :test => true

Can anyone tell me what the deal is?

---

### UPDATE

So I decided it was best to absolutely verify that the problem was with authorize.net---  Turns out, it's not.. If I do the request via curl, it is successful:

```
    curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
      <merchantAuthentication>
        <name>myTestLogin</name>
        <transactionKey>myTransactionKey</transactionKey>
      </merchantAuthentication>
      <profile>
        <merchantCustomerId>custId123</merchantCustomerId>
        <description>some description</description>
        <email>foo@bar.com</email>
      </profile>
    </createCustomerProfileRequest>' https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api


      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><createCustomerProfileResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"><messages><resultCode>Ok</resultCode><message><code>I00001</code><text>Successful.</text></message></messages><customerProfileId>10521778</customerProfileId><customerPaymentProfileIdList /><customerShippingAddressIdList /><validationDirectResponseList /></createCustomerProfileResponse>
```

...

So, this means the problem is with ActiveMerchant........  I can create customer profiles just fine with my live, real-world account through activemerchant, but for some reason, I cannot do it to the developer test account...

There is one thing that makes me suspicious:

Despite the fact that the gateways says it's in test mode:
1.9.3p194 :007 > GATEWAY
 => #, :password=>, :test=>true}>

actually inquiring if it's in test mode returns an unexpected response........

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > GATEWAY.test?
 => false
```

hmmmmmmmmmmm...

Answer (score 0):

Test mode and setting `test` to `true` are two different things. If your account is in test mode you should set `test` to `false` or don't send it at all.

Better yet, if you're in the process of developing an application you should sign up for a [developer account](http://developer.authorize.net/integration/) with Authorize.Net. That way you don't have to deal with test modes or parameters since developer accounts are essentially always in test mode. They act like production accounts but don't actually process any payments. It makes developing easier and safer.

Comment: The first line of my question says "I created a developer account with authorize.net".  I tried setting test to false..  It makes no difference.  I cannot create a profile with activemerchant with a developer account.  As I said in my post, I can do it fine with a "real" account, but not with the developer test account.